# Query statistics on number of nodes created or edges added

Tags: typescript, gremlin, amazon-neptune

OpenCypher provides statistics on number of nodes created or number of edges updated as a result of query execution :

```
queryResult.summary?.updateStatistics?.updates()?.nodesCreated
```

I'm trying to find if there's a similar mechanism for Gremlin; explain/profile API return predicates but not the information on number of edges/nodes affected.

I'd appreciate any insights.

Edit:
For example, the query below:

```
const traversal = this.__.addV(label) .property(GREMLIN_ID, id) .property("created_timestamp", new Date().getTime()); this.logger.info("Add vertex if not exist "); 
const v = await this.g .V(id) .fold() .coalesce(this.__.unfold(), traversal) .elementMap() .next(); 
return v.value;
```

This would add a new vertex only if it doesn't already exist; when it does get executed though, would like to find if there's a way to see the number of "new" nodes added as a result of the query execution.

Update:
With Kevin's solution, was able to retrieve edge counts as well:

```
g.inject(0).store('edgeCount').coalesce(
          V('0000x', 'facade00-0000-4000-a000-000000000000')
          .hasLabel("FINGERPRINT")
          .outE()
          .where(V().with('0000x', 'facade00-0000-4000-a000-000000000000')),
        V('0000x', 'facade00-0000-4000-a000-000000000000')
        .hasLabel("FINGERPRINT")
        .as("from")
        .V('0000x', 'facade00-0000-4000-a000-000000000000')
        .hasLabel("RDC_VISITOR_ID")
        .as("to")
        .addE("ANONYMOUS")
        .from("from")
        .to("to")
        .sideEffect(constant(1).store('edgeCount'))
      ).project('edge','count').by().by(cap('edgeCount').unfold().sum())
```

This gives:

```
{'edge': e[191][0000x-ANONYMOUS->facade00-0000-4000-a000-000000000000], 'count': 1}
```

And count becomes `0` with further executions. Thanks!

Comment: In Gremlin you will need to return the answer as part of the query (or run a subsequent query to check). If you can share an example of a query you are running I will be happy to help adding an example of how to return those statistics from the query.

Comment: Sure. For instance, the following code: ```   const traversal = this.__.addV(label)
        .property(GREMLIN_ID, id)
        .property("created_timestamp", new Date().getTime());
      this.logger.info("Add vertex if not exist ");
      const v = await this.g
        .V(id)
        .fold()
        .coalesce(this.__.unfold(), traversal)
        .elementMap()
        .next();
      return v.value;``` - this would add a vertex only if it doesn't exist in the graph db. Is there a way to return the number of nodes added as a part of this query execution ? Else resultset is usually same.

Comment: Could you please add that to the question? It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, updated to be a part of the question.

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to keep track of work done by the query using `store`. I was not able to get it to work the way I wanted using `sack`. If I figure that out, I will update the answer.

The count should be one as we are creating a new vertex.

```java
gremlin> g.inject(0).store('x').
......1>   V('A1').
......2>   fold().
......3>   coalesce(
......4>     unfold(),
......5>     addV('test').property(id,'A1').sideEffect(constant(1).store('x'))).
......6>   project('vertex','count').
......7>     by().
......8>     by(cap('x').unfold().sum()) 
==>[vertex:v[A1],count:1]
```

It's created now, so the count should be 0.

```java
gremlin> g.inject(0).store('x').
......1>   V('A1').
......2>   fold().
......3>   coalesce(
......4>     unfold(),
......5>     addV('test').property(id,'A1').sideEffect(constant(1).store('x'))).
......6>   project('vertex','count').
......7>     by().
......8>     by(cap('x').unfold().sum()) 

==>[vertex:v[A1],count:0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful ! Will replicate this for getting edge count too.